# prevent form from becoming invalid after press submit in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I did a validation using:

```
ng-show="myForm.name.$invalid && !myForm.name.$pristine"
```

Everything works perfectly, but when I press 'submit', I need to empty the input fields in this way:

```
$scope.people.name = '';
$scope.people.surname = '';
```

so the form becomes invalid after the submit...is there a way to prevent that? I need empty fields but a valid form...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess after clearing your model variables you need to set forms $pristine property

```
$scope.form.$setPristine();
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/815Bml?p=preview